# velocity Template DateFormat

Tags: java, velocity

I am having problem while converting date format, but problem is while concate.
This is code am using in Velocity Template.

```
#if($order.ordqty)"$order.ordqty" 
#end 

#if($order.etd) "$format.getFormatedDate("dd-MM-yyyy", $order.etd)" 
#end
```

Output: This is not working

```
#if($order.ordqty)"$order.ordqty 
#end

#if($order.etd) @$order.etd" 
#end
```

Output: it works well --output==1200@Thursday 10 2012

```
#if($order.etd) "$format.getFormatedDate("dd-MM-yyyy", $order.etd)" 
#end
```

Output: it works well   12-12-2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#if($finaldate) 
   #set( $finaldate = $format.getFormatedDate("dd-MM-yyyy", $order.etd) )    
   "$finaldate" 
#end
```

OR

```
#if($DOMASTER.issuedate) 
     $format.getFormatedDate("dd-MM-yyyy", $DOMASTER.issuedate) 
#end
```

Due to the "" problem  exists it is solved by creating another variable for date manipulation.